# WordPress - Display different HTML elements on Homepage

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to display different header sections on the home screen and article screen. I thought something like this would work:

```
<? php if( is_home() ) { ?>
  <header class="header home" role="banner">
  <?php  } else { ?>
  <header class="header" role="banner">
  <?php
 }
?>
```

Where, in my CSS, the following takes place:

```
.header {
    background: $blue;

    &.home {
        background: $blue; 
    }
}
```

In reality I *should* see a green header on the home page, and a blue one on the homepage. But I don't. Any clues?

Comment: You test always your code, ask to him:
echo is_home();
echo is_front_page();
so you can know where you are.

Enjoy your code!

Comment: No, you shouldn't use echo in if condition. Use alone. <?php echo is_home(); ?> or better <?php var_dump(is_home()); ?>. So you can test the boolean return by function is_home and is_front_page(). Let me know the result.

Comment: For display any error on your page use this istruction at top of the page: <?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>

Comment: Hmm still isn't displaying anything. Sorry I know this must be frustrating. This is what my current code looks like:

<?php if ( echo is_home() ) {
<header class="header" role="banner">
} else {
<header class="header" role="banner"> 
}
?>

Comment: <?php var_dump(is_home()); exit; if ( is_home() ) { <header class="header" role="banner"> } else { <header class="header" role="banner"> } ?> What display?

Comment: Still nothing. Maybe there's something going wrong somewhere else in my page. Is there a way on Stackoverflow that I can send you a larger sample of my code without it being via an inline comment?

Comment: Yes when I save my code and go to the browser to refresh, it remains a blank page.

Comment: Show or active Apache log, then show them. The problem is that you dont Display the error. ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log". Follow this tutorial: http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/vhosts_mamp.php

Comment: It's okay - I really don't have the time to go through that entire tutorial to get an error display. I might just refactor the code and see if I can spot the error. Thanks for all your help :) I really appreciate it.

Comment: It's not the space between <? and 'php', really? In your posted code there is a space.

Comment: My good friend - you have just solved the issue! The code I originally posted actually works fine - but there was a missing space between the <? and 'php' as per your suggestion! Thank you so much :)

Comment: Please make a reply comment so I can mark it as the right answer so you can receive the credit your deserve! :)

Comment: Don't mention it. :)
Enjoy your code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the last, we have discovered that the problem is a single space between <? and 'php'.

Thanks and Enjoy your code!

Answer (score 1):

try after change this

```
<? php if( is_home() ) { ?>
```

to

```
<? php if( is_home() || is_front_page() ) { ?>
```

Comment: Still no luck. Funnily enough, my page is no longer rendering. Perhaps I have a missing bracket?

Comment: is css class is okay ? are yo including css in header , you can try to change the name of class

Comment: echo anything other than code in if else condition so that you can dbug if its a php error or html

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the code you posted is the code you're using code, you apply the `$blue` attribute to both `.header` and `.header.home` instead of applying something like `$green` to one of them.

```
.header {
    background: $blue;

    &.home {
        background: $blue; 
    }
}
```

If you've declared a variable $green to hold a hexadecimal value representing a green color try

```
.header {
    background: $blue;

    &.home {
        background: $green; 
    }
}
```

See this JSFiddle for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/SSCnJ/

Comment: Sorry about that - it was actually a silly CSS mistake I picked up on as soon as I posted the above message!

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the solution, but you could also try changing this

```
 background: $blue;
```

to this

```
 background-color: $blue;
```

assuming that $blue holds either a hexadecimal value with a # in front, or is an rgba value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah it's a SASS variable. The $blue variable holds a hexadecimal color value :)

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
<? php if( is_front_page() ) { ?>
    <header class="header home" role="banner">
    <?php  } else { ?>
    <header class="header" role="banner">
    <?php
  }
?>
```

is_home() will return true on home page only if you have set Front page displays -> Your latest posts  in Reading settings.

For more info read http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home#Blog_Posts_Index_vs._Site_Front_Page

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately the entire page is now no longer rendering on load. My local MAMP address is displaying a blank page :(

Comment: Also FYI my current settings have been set to display most recent posts. This is the way I've designed the webpage so I'd like to retain that homepage type if possible :)